# Subset of nilpotent mappings of self maps is not open

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, nilpotence

Prove that the subset of all nilpotent mappings of $L(U)$ where $U$ is a finite dimensional normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is not an open subset.

Also, does this generalize to *any* finite dimensional vector space?

Comment: You should be able to find a sequence in the complement converging to something nilpotent, hence the complement is not closed. It does generalise to any finite-dimensional vector space, since any topology for which vector addition and scalar multiplication are continuous is equivalent to the topology induced by any norm - you can read more about that [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/topology/finite-dim-TVS.pdf).

Comment: The nilpotent maps are the ones with characteristic polynomial $t^{\dim U}$, so it follows that the subspace of nilpotent maps is closed (in the norm topology but also even in the Zariski topology). Then it can't be open because $L(U)$ is connected and the nilpotent maps aren't the entire space.